# Spliting a file into lines in Python using re.split

Tags: python, regex, list-comprehension

I'm trying to split a file with a list comprehension using code similar to:

```
lines = [x for x in re.split(r"\n+", file.read()) if not re.match(r"com", x)]
```

However, the lines list always has an empty string as the last element. Does anyone know a way to avoid this (excluding the cludge of putting a pop() afterwards)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Put the regular expression hammer away :-)

1. You can iterate over a file directly; `readlines()` is almost obsolete these days.
2. Read about [`str.strip()`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip) (and its friends, `lstrip()` and `rstrip()`).
3. Don't use `file` as a variable name.  It's bad form, because `file` is a [built-in function](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#file).

You can write your code as:

```
lines = []
f = open(filename)
for line in f:
    if not line.startswith('com'):
        lines.append(line.strip())
```

If you are still getting blank lines in there, you can add in a test:

```
lines = []
f = open(filename)
for line in f:
    if line.strip() and not line.startswith('com'):
        lines.append(line.strip())
```

If you really want it in one line:

```
lines = [line.strip() for line in open(filename) if line.strip() and not line.startswith('com')]
```

Finally, if you're on python 2.6, look at the [with statement](http://effbot.org/zone/python-with-statement.htm) to improve things a little more.

Comment: I haven't written any Python since last year, and I'm recovering from a short but nasty bout of PERL.

Thanks to your answer I'm getting back in the mindset :)

Answer (score 3):

lines = file.readlines()

**edit:**
or if you didnt want blank lines in there, you can do

lines = filter(lambda a:(a!='\n'), file.readlines())

**edit^2:**
to remove trailing newines, you can do

lines = [re.sub('\n','',line) for line in filter(lambda a:(a!='\n'), file.readlines())]

Comment: Leaves the trailing newlines on. I'm not sure if that's an issue for OP.

Comment: file.readlines() is not quite the same...
It includes the newline at the end of each line, and includes empty lines.

Answer (score 1):

another handy trick, especially when you need the line number, is to use enumerate:

```
fp = open("myfile.txt", "r")
for n, line in enumerate(fp.readlines()):
    dosomethingwith(n, line)
```

i only found out about enumerate quite recently but it has come in handy quite a few times since then.

Answer (score 0):

This should work, and eliminate the regular expressions as well:

```
all_lines = (line.rstrip()
             for line in open(filename)
             if "com" not in line)
# filter out the empty lines
lines = filter(lambda x : x, all_lines)
```

Since you're using a list comprehension and not a generator expression (so the whole file gets loaded into memory anyway), here's a shortcut that avoids code to filter out empty lines:

```
lines = [line
     for line in open(filename).read().splitlines()
     if "com" not in line]
```

Comment: Instead of 'filter(lambda x: x, all_lines)', you can just write 'filter(None, all_lines)'.  Although I've never been totally happy with that short-cut :-)